# Getting number of fields in a database with an SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, database, get, field

How would I get the number of fields/entries in a database using an SQL Statement?

Comment: are you asking how to get the number of attributes a table has plus the amount of rows in the table?

Comment: What do you mean by fields / entries? Do you mean number of Rows? Number of Columns? Number of Tables? All of the above? If so, which database engine are you using?

Comment: "entries" in a database? do you mean records, or columns in a table, or number of tables?

Comment: I think he means all entries in a database. That would be all entries in every table of that DB combined

Answer (score 30, accepted):

mmm all the fields in all the tables? assuming standards (mssql, mysql, postgres) you can issue a query over information_schema.columns

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Or grouped by table:

```
  SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

If multiple schemas has the same table name in the same DB, you MUST include schema name as well (i.e: dbo.Books, user.Books, company.Books etc.) Otherwise you'll get the wrong results. So the best practice is:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: FYI that will also include views

Comment: In any case, he doesn't specified the engine, and that behavior could be specific of mssql.

Comment: both MySQL and PostgreSQL have table_type in information_schema.tables

Comment: Information schema is an ANSI standard.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Schema

Comment: Even though this is a very old thread the answers given will include the columns of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table, which you probably don't want in your count.   I have 315 columns in my INFORMATION_SCHEMA table. Use SELECT * to see what you are counting before you use SELECT COUNT(*):   `SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  where TABLE_SCHEMA != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' `

Answer (score 4):

try this, this will exclude views, leave the where clause out if you want views

```
  select count(*) from information_schema.columns c
join information_schema.tables t on c.table_name = t.table_name
and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is what you need.

```
select CountOfFieldsInDatabase = count(*)
from   information_schema.columns
```

Comment: its counting ROWS in the table that describes the columns.  One row per column in the database.

Comment: @Ken: No, it's definitely counting the number of columns across all tables in the DB. (Which is a slightly useless thing to want to do, but it is what the OP asked for.)

Comment: Ken, each row will be for one column

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = **name of your table here **
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for any other readers who are googling...

There are several non-SQL solutions, that may be useful to the user..
here's 2 that I use.

Example 1:
Access VBA:

```
'Microsoft Access VBA
Function Count_Fields(Table_Name As String) As Integer
    Dim myFieldCount As Integer
    Dim db As DOA.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(Table_Name, dbOpenDynaset)
    myFieldCount = rs.Fields.Count
    'return the count
    Count_Fields = myFieldCount
    'tidy up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Example 2:
PHP 5.1:

```
    <?php
    // PHP5 Implementation - uses MySQLi.
    function countFields ($tableName) { 
    $db = new mysqli('myserver.me.com', 'user' ,'pass', 'databasename');
    if(!$db) {
        echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
        } 
    else {
        $rs->$db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$tableName.");
        $fieldCount = $rs->field_count;
        }
    return $fieldCount;
?>
```

please excuse any typo's in the above - hope someone finds this useful