# SQL: Count number of columns in all tables, excluding views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am creating a query that returns the number of columns in each table, but I want to exclude Views.

The following works but returns View results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Group By table_name
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE:  MSSQL 2005+

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033726/getting-number-of-fields-in-a-database-with-an-sql-statement

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This assumes SQL 2005 or higher

```
SELECT 
    t.name,
    count(c.name)
FROM 

    sys.tables t 
    inner join sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id


group by t.name
```

Comment: Output is two columns "Name of Table" and "Column Count"; Perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(col.column_name), col.table_name
FROM information_schema.columns col
  JOIN information_schema.tables tbl 
       ON tbl.table_name = col.table_name 
          AND tbl.table_schema = col.table_schema
          AND tbl.table_catalog = col.table_catalog
          AND tbl.table_type <> 'VIEW'
GROUP BY col.table_name
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'schema_name'.
Invalid column name 'catalog_name'.

Answer (score 0):

Join `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to find out if the table is a view.

```
SELECT COUNT(col.column_name), tab.table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables tab
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col ON col.table_name = tab.table_name
WHERE tab.table_type != 'VIEW'
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Error in 2024: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  tab.table_name,COUNT(col.column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables tab
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col ON col.table_name = tab.table_name
WHERE tab.table_type != 'VIEW'
GROUP BY tab.table_name 
ORDER BY tab.table_name
```

This code shows the table names and their columns count in front of them.
you can add the schema name if you want.